tor ipv4 address not working with orport (dynamic ip)
Does anyone know if tor works properly with a dynamic ipv4 address? I'm running a tor guard relay but it seems to only be connecting on IPv6 (Port 9001 and 443) but IPv4 works on neither. Log file reports that it's checking the IPv4 orport but it never connects. I think the IPv4 address is more important for tor relays so I would like to know if this is a DNS problem or related issue. I'm connected from my phone's hotspot if that helps. OS is PClinuxOS GNU/Linux.

No, it's fine - the descriptor is published, so after a check-up the Tor network will know your address. Dynamic IP works fine too - but, of course, not as good as a static one. IPv6 is a preferred protocol to make the connection over on almost all modern OS'es, so that's why you do have most of the traffic going through IPv6
